# How can I load a view controller in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following code in viewDidLoad. I want to compare a nsdate I have saved in nsuserdefaults restrictionTime.

```
if ([[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:[restrictionTime objectForKey:@"time"]] < 86400) {

    ResultsViewController *destinationViewController = [[ResultsViewController alloc]init];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    destinationViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"results"];

    [self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:^{
    }]; // !!!!! this line 

}
```

***When it gets to the line specified in the code, the app runs viewDidLoad recursively.*** All I want to do is compare the time now and the time I saved in NSUserDefaults. If it is less than a day, then it will present another viewController.

*if I comment out the line specified above, it runs fine.

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:[restrictionTime objectForKey:@"time"]]);
```

The above NSLog returns 2167.23445.

Comment: DON'T present any view controller before you view has appeared!

Comment: you should not try to push a new view into the navigation stack until `–viewDidAppear:` method is called in the view lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running viewDidLoad recursively, that suggests to me that you are calling the same VC again through:

```
    destinationViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"results"];
```

Can you verify that this is not intentional? I am confused as to why you would possibly instantiate the same VC again. If this is the problem, I recommend you double check the name of the VC you actually want to instantiate in the event this scenario is true.

Comment: 100% certain that I'm not calling the same VC

Comment: Can you breakpoint the beginning of the viewDidLoad function being called and look on your stack trace to see who is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two view controllers in this block:

```
// Creating a ResultsViewController
ResultsViewController *destinationViewController = [[ResultsViewController alloc]init];

// Creating (I assume) another ResultsViewController
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
destinationViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"results"];
```

Are you sure you mean "recursively"?  Or do you mean twice?  Also as others have mentioned, you should probably be presenting the new controller in -viewDidAppear: